# How to wait for postgres startup in ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker

What would be the best approach to wait for `postgres` to fully start up inside my `ENTRYPOINT` before moving on executing `nosetests`?

Right now I've timed the startup on my machine to around 50 seconds. So I'm just sleeping for 60 seconds. This does not feel good as this might not work when being run on another machine.

```
ENTRYPOINT \
           runuser -l postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf & ' && \
           sleep 60 && \
           nosetests --verbose --cover-erase --with-coverage --cover-package=stalker
```

This is the output of starting up `postgres`:

```
2017-02-13 13:46:49.541 UTC [9] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-02-13 12:53:23 UTC
2017-02-13 13:47:37.951 UTC [9] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2017-02-13 13:47:37.994 UTC [9] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1783EA0
2017-02-13 13:47:37.995 UTC [9] LOG:  record with zero length at 0/17841E8
2017-02-13 13:47:37.995 UTC [9] LOG:  redo done at 0/17841B8
2017-02-13 13:47:37.995 UTC [9] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2017-02-13 12:53:23.731984+00
2017-02-13 13:47:38.384 UTC [9] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-02-13 13:47:38.387 UTC [7] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-02-13 13:47:38.387 UTC [13] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Please, I do understand that this goes against the convention of running multiple commands in `ENTRYPOINT`. I have good reasons to do this in this case.

Comment: You could run [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-isready.html) in a loop while the return code is 1.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to @zeppelin for suggesting `pg_isready`. I ended up using this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

cmd="$@"
timer="5"

until runuser -l postgres -c 'pg_isready' 2>/dev/null; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping for $timer seconds"
  sleep $timer
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

I'm using this in my `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT \

            # Start PostgreSQL
            runuser -l postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf & ' && \

            # Exectute tests when db is up
            ./wait-for-postgres.sh nosetests --verbose --cover-erase --with-coverage --cover-package=stalker
```

Answer (score 7):

I will normally use a small "tcp-port-wait" script, like this:

```js
#!/bin/bash
set -e 

if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]
then
    echo "tcp-port-wait - block until specified TCP port becomes available"
    echo "Usage: ntcp-port-wait HOST PORT"
    exit 1
fi
echo Waiting for port $1:$2 to become available...
while ! nc -z $1 $2 2>/dev/null
do
    let elapsed=elapsed+1
    if [ "$elapsed" -gt 90 ] 
    then
        echo "TIMED OUT !"
        exit 1
    fi  
    sleep 1;
done

echo "READY !"
```

To wait until a certain service is up and ready.

In case of Postgresql, the default port it will listen on is *5432*, so the command would be:

```
tcp-port-wait localhost 5432
```

That will block until Postgresql service is ready to serve connections, on :5432 on the loopback interface inside the container (when run in context of the ENTRYPOINT script).

You certainly have to copy this script into your container,
by adding a line like that to your *Dockerfile*:

```
COPY tcp-port-wait /usr/local/bin/
```

before you can use it.

And also install the *netcat* utility.

You can use this for other types of services, like Tomcat or Mysql, too.

And, if you need, you can also wait "outside the container", like this:

```js
docker exec my_container tcp-port-wait localhost 5432
```

Note, there are certainly other ways to do this, e.g. by using some orchestration tool, like *docker-compose* with [healthcheck directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/healthcheck), or some process manager inside the container itself.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, apparently it is accepting connections while recovery is in progress, try to replace `nc -z $1 $2` with `pg_isready` (which is a PostgreSQL-specific utility for checking it's status), and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, using `pg_isready` worked! Also, I had to remove the check for the arguments. If you like to modify your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.